# My VBA excel code runs on Mac Excel but not Windows Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into an issue where my VBA macro works on my MAC Excel application, but not on a Windows Excel application. There error I am getting is

> Run-time error ‘438’ Object doesn’t support this property or method

The code is below

```vb
Sub AutoSort()
'
' AutoSort Macro
'

'


    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C2:C946" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "Priority,Active,Tracking,Inactive", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AE946")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

It is erroring off at line of code

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C2:C946" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "Priority,Active,Tracking,Inactive", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Is that the actual code, or did you retype it into the question missing some characters in the process?

Comment: I edited the question to include the full code copied and pasted. The line I entered first was where the code was erroring of.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Excel 2016?

Comment: I'm running office / Excel 2016. I do not believe that `Sort2` is available in Excel 2016.

Comment: @DillonDavenport Try installing any pending Office updates.

Answer (score 2):

`Add2` was added recently to Excel to support new field types. Not all versions of Excel support it. I have an Office Pro 2016 and it is not supported, but running Office 365 Pro (on a VM) supports it. No clue about Office for Mac, but obviously your version supports it.

It seems that if your office version supports the `Add2`-command, the Macro recorder will use that. However, in most of the cases it should okay just to change to the "old" method `Add`.

Comment: I have Excel 2016 Professional Plus, it is supported there.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this:** Tested on Excel - 2016

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("C2:C946") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "Priority,Active,Tracking,Inactive", DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange Range("A1:AE946")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Error could be because the `Key` Range is not referenced with the Sheet Name.

Comment: There could be an error because of that, but not the error 438.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the Error, but for once I did receive the Error 438. Couldn't identify the reason, but this code works.

Comment: Yes, for a Different Range and Sheet Name

Comment: Then this version is very unlikely to fix it for them either.